# Planning users in project

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm fresh in Symfony. To go further with my project I try today to plan how to organize "users". In my project I will have few different type of accounts:

- A administrator
- G guardian
- KC known customer
- KCX known customer with sub accounts
- NC new customer

I know how every type of user will be created in project.

- A - defined in advance (only one account)
- G - created by A, A will put email and name in simple form, and after that G will get e-mail with link to set the password (more than 1 accounts)
- NC - normal register form on website with access for every not logged in user
- KC - A or G will upgrade NC by setting internal customer code in NC's data
- KCX - it will be sub account for KC with separated e-mail and password to log in, this type of account could be set only by KC user

So, as you can see, only NC user is created by standard register form. Standard registration I can solve by FOSUserBundle. But how to solve other things? 
 - How to let A create new G?
 - How to let A and G upgrade NC to KC?
 - How to let KC create KCX?

Should I use security.yml and try to solve everything by roles?

Best regards, I will be thankful for any advice.
L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of these actions you should create Controller actions that will only allow users with certain roles access. From these actions you will retrieve users from your database and handle as you would handle any other objects.

Restrictions for routes(and controller actions behind them) are set within security.yml.

FOSUserBundle is not required for this setup at all. If you do not know full capabilities of that bundle, you might want to refrain from using it in your custom setup.

Comment: Thanks. Is it good idea to use one controller and manage access by this kind of ifs https://pastebin.com/wEQJgJ56 ?

Comment: @Lukaszy if you need one method to do different things for different users - this is fine. If that method is only allowed for certain role - allow only that role in security.yml.